# How can I choose a 3rd tag?

Tags: html, css

I have problems selecting the third input tag, below is the code, check it out for me, thanks

```
<div class="form-login">
    <form>
        <label>Email address</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="account" placeholder="Entet your email"><br>
        <label>Password</label><br>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password"><br>
        <input type="radio" name="remember"><label>Remember me</label><br>
        <button type="button" >
            Login now
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

```
.form-login form input:nth-child(3){}
```

Comment: `.form-login input[name="remember"]` could work for this as well, using the attribute selector

Comment: .form-login input[type=radio] if there is only 1 radio button else you can use name attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input:nth-child(3)` selects the third child of input which doesn't exist. You need to use `nth-of-type`.

`.form-login form input:nth-of-type(3){}`

Answer (score 0):

This code for picking up your label;

```
.form-login form label:nth-of-type(3){}
```

That one is for your checkbox;

```
.form-login form input:nth-of-type(3){}
```